# Use same input text for two button using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view

I want to use the same text to go different View.At present I set two view one is PlaceInformation and another is Google Map View. How can I set condition to go both View using HTML Beginfrom.I want to use @using (Html.BeginForm("GoogleMapView", "Home")) here. My Code sample is look like this-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PlaceInformation", "Home"))
{
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m =>m.Name)
                <label for="somevalue">City Name</label>
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </div>
                  <div class="input-group-btn">
                     <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Map View</button>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  }
```

This is how i modified code .But it is not working.

```
<form id="myForm">

<div class="wrapper wrapper-content">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
            <label for="somevalue">City Name</label>

            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="mapViewBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Map View</button>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
  <script> {
   $("#searchBtn").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/home/placeinformation',
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function (data) {
            //here you will get the result from the Controllers, like a partial view or you can do a redirect to another view if form post is successful.
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
           //Handle any errors here
        }
    });
  });
 }
 </script>

<script>{
  $("#mapViewBtn").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/home/GoogleMap',
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function (data) {
            //here you will get the result from the Controllers, like a partial view or you can do a redirect to another view if form post is successful.
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
           //Handle any errors here
        }
    });
   });
 }
 </script>
```

My Controller for GoogleMap is-

```
    public ActionResult GoogleMap(City objCityModel)
     {
        string name = objCityModel.Name;
        ViewBag.Title = name;

        var ReadJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/POI_Json/" + name + ".json"));

        RootObject json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(ReadJson);
        List<Poi> mycities = new List<Poi>();

        foreach (var item in json.poi)
        {
            Poi obj = new Poi()
            {
                Name = item.Name,
                Shorttext = item.Shorttext,
                GeoCoordinates = item.GeoCoordinates,
                Images = item.Images,

            };
            mycities.Add(obj);
        }

        ViewBag.Cities = mycities;

        return View();

    }
```

For Getting the name-

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(City objCityModel)
    {
        string name = objCityModel.Name;
        return View();
    }
```

in My PLace information I am using the same data as GoogleMap view

```
 public ActionResult PlaceInformation(City objCityModel)
    {

        string name = objCityModel.Name;
        ViewBag.Title = name;

        var ReadJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/POI_Json/" + name + ".json"));

        RootObject json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(ReadJson);
        List<Poi> mycities = new List<Poi>();

        foreach (var item in json.poi)
        {
            Poi obj = new Poi()
            {
                Name = item.Name,
                Shorttext = item.Shorttext,
                GeoCoordinates = item.GeoCoordinates,
                Images = item.Images,

            };
            mycities.Add(obj);
        }

        ViewBag.Cities = mycities;

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: using (Html.BeginForm("PlaceInformation", "Home", new { Id = myForm }))// showing error should be using (Html.BeginForm("PlaceInformation", "Home", new { Id = "myForm" }))// or <form id="myForm"> and then replace the closing bracelet'}' with end tag </form>

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson: Now error is gone but both button goes in the same PalceInformation View

Comment: Hitting Map View button won't get the call to placeinformation?

Comment: yes it goes to PlaceInformation. But I need Home/GoogleMap

Comment: No [HttpPost] on GoogleMap action?

Comment: No, But I have not also [HttpPost] for PlaceInformation

Comment: I can't see PlaceIformation action? Index?

Comment: Change public ActionResult GoogleMap(City objCityModel)
to public JsonResult GoogleMap(City objCityModel). Since we are calling it with javascript you wont get reirected via the controller but have to do thatin the js success method instead. Anr return something like "Ok".

Comment: Ah, and I see. You should add <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"/> above the other scripts. If you press F12 in chrome on you form page you probably see som errors right?

Comment: But what should I return then?

Comment: yes I can see the same error

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson: I have a question why did you write this line using (Html.BeginForm("PlaceInformation", "Home", It means it goes alway in Place information. And another this is if i reference the link everything become freeze. nothing happen. If i remove it then i can go to the placeinformation page but also the google button goes in the same page

Comment: I think you should replace that line with <form id="myForm">

Comment: @MagnusKarlsson: I modified my question. are you telling to write Form in this way. But it is also not working.

Comment: That wont work since it was malformed, you have to close the form tag with a form tag. Updaed my answer to refelct that. What program do you use to edit you code?

Comment: Ok. I have a question you write to // serializes the form's elements. What can I do here.because I write Name in text box it goes http://localhost:53423/?Name=kiel . but not in Home/PlaceInformation

Comment: Looks like jQuery isnt added correctly. Can you confirm it is downloaded with Chrome dev tools? By the way, what are you using to write your code?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

This will only generate one html form and it is the form element that decides where the form is posted. In other words there is no way to post this form to different controller actions depending on the button being clicked. However, there are of course other ways. I would bind and post the two post buttons with jQuery like this:

Change .cshtml to this:

```
<form id="myForm"> 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        <label for="somevalue">City Name</label>

        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="mapViewBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Map View</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

Add id to the buttons:

```
 <div class="input-group-btn">
     <button id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
 </div>
 <div class="input-group-btn">
     <button id="mapViewBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Map View</button>
 </div>
```

script:

```
$("#searchBtn").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/home/placeinformation',
            data: $("#myForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function (data) {
                //here you will get the result from the Controllers, like a partial view or you can do a redirect to another view if form post is successful.
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
               //Handle any errors here
            }
        });
    });
}
```

second script (I changed the button you bind to and the controller action you want to call.

```
    $("#mapViewBtn").on("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/home/urlToTheOtherAction,
            data: $("#myForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function (data) {
                //here you will get the result from the Controllers, like a partial view or you can do a redirect to another view if form post is successful.
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
               //Handle any errors here
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what is Id= myForm here

Comment: So, the razor syntac(C# in cshtml files) only creates/render html which you can see in the browser. The id attribute will generate an id attribute connected to you form element. It is unique and we need it for the  data: $("#myForm").serialize() row in the ajax call to work. That line will take your form based on the id and send it to the serverjust like a click on one of the buttons would have done but we effectively prevents on the first line on both scripts.

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("PlaceInformation", "Home", new { Id = myForm})) will turn out like this in your browser: <form id="myForm" action="/home/PlaceInformation/"> so you canactually simplify your code now and change it to <form id="myForm">.

Comment: Myform shows error. it tells MyForm does not exist in the current folder or location

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more or modify your code. I am very new handling this situation. Thank you very much

Comment: I have modified my code according to your answer. But As I d´said it is showing error for Id=myForm

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("PlaceInformation", "Home", new { Id = "myForm" }))// showing error
 {
I had forgot the "" around myForm id. Updated answer.

Comment: Then you should post your controller action and ask how you can fix that code instead. If you update your answer I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I have edited my question and add GoogleMap Controller